# Oracle : Eliminate the error

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle9i, ora-06550

I have the holiday table whose description are

```
   Name                                      Null?    Type
```

---

```
 HOLIDAYDATE                                        DATE
 DESCRIPTION                                        VARCHAR2(20)
```

which contains data are

```
HOLIDAYDA DESCRIPTION
--------- --------------------
19-JAN-11 to
17-JAN-11 to
10-JAN-11 a
```

here is my code :

```
DECLARE a date;
SELECT holidaydate 
  INTO a 
  FROM holiday 
 WHERE holidaydate = SYSDATE;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(a);
```

i am receiving error like this.

**ERROR at line 2:
  ORA-06550: line 2, column 1:
  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" when expecting one of the following:
  begin function package pragma procedure subtype type use
    form
  current cursor**

Can anyone tell me what is the problem in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
declare 
  a date;
begin
  select holidaydate into a from holiday where holidaydate = sysdate;
  dbms_output.put_line(a);
end;
```

But this will probably give you a new error (no data found), because there probably is no record that has Sysdate entered in Holidaydate, because sysdate includes the time as well.

So try this:

```
declare 
  a date;
begin
  select 
    (select holidaydate from holiday where holidaydate = trunc(sysdate))
  into a 
  from dual;

  dbms_output.put_line(a);
end;
```

That will cut off the time part, checking for whole dates. If there are whole dates in your table as well, this will more likely give a result. If not, the select from dual will capture that, and make `a` return NULL.

The only error you may get now, is when there are more than one records containing the same date.

Comment: +1: This is called an anonymous PLSQL block, signified by the `BEGIN` and `END` keywords.

Comment: how can i execute the above query? i ran it in sql plus and i received the output as Pl/sql successfully completed.but it doesnt shows any output.